# данные в button navigation

Tags: android

Сейчас я начал работать с button navigation и мне надо вписать туда данные и как их найти, ну например eeditText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName); но я не знаю куда вписывать эти данные и где работать, т.к. там везде стоит privat

```
package my.file.myapplication1.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import my.file.myapplication1.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button load;

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Никакого `button navigation` не существует. Вы, наверное, имеете в виду `BottomNavigationView`. Если да - переформулируйте вопрос, т.к. не ясно что и куда вам надо добавить и при чём тут приведённый вами код. Также не надо код картинкой добавлять - так мы не сможем его скопировать и вам исправить. А набирать код вручную по картинке мало кому захочется, т.к. важнейшее качесство программиста - лень.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я внес код вместо фотографии, еще раз скажу что надо сделать, у меня есть переменная например Edittext и мне надо понять куда я могу ее вписать чтобы найти по id и где мне в дальнейшем с ней работать

Comment: А находится этот Edittext где? В разметке того же фрагмента что и показан у вас в вопросе? Если да, то можете аналогично его находить в  onCreateView или используйте (что лучше) `onViewCreated()` метод. Если не в этом фрагменте, то всё на порядок сложнее, в этом фрагменте вы не сможете найти Edittext (на самом деле можно при ряде условий, но это будет очень неправильно и я не буду рассказывать как, т.к. это плохо =)).

Comment: я уже решил эту проблему, я не в ту активность пытался вписать данные